# When using OCCI deleting runs forever

Tags: sql, oracle, occi

the same line:

```
DELETE(SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id=12)
```

on SQL Developer runs normally and when using the occi API takes forever.

I have checked that the query "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id=12" matches a non empty sets of rows.

More specifically I use the following syntax:

```
oracle::occi::Statement *deleteStm = con->createStatement("DELETE(SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id=12)");
oracle::occi::ResultSet *rs = deleteStm->executeQuery();
```

Comment: Did you commit your transaction?

Comment: No, I didn't. But I cannot see how this can help: when running with the debugger I never get out of the executeQuery() line. Where should I commit the transaction?

Comment: @lad2025 tanks!

Comment: @lad2025  I committed just before deleting and it worked. Can you explain why, even though the query "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id=12" returns a match, I cannot delete the newly inserted (non commited) line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that in your case you've simply got uncommitted transaction. It goes that way:

```
session1                   session2
DELETE ...                                        table/rows is locked

                           SELECT * FROM ...      you will see all data

                           DELETE ...             and now you will wait and wait
                                                  until lock is released

COMMIT;
                           SELECT * FROM ...      now resultset is empty
```

I strongly encourage to read [Data Concurrency and Consistency](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/consist.htm#CNCPT020)